# Comic book with a TV used as an interdimensional portal

Tags: story-identification, comics

I'm looking for a comic book that I read in the 90s. I only remember that the comic book starts with the main character taking back his TV from the pawn shop (repair place?). After the guy leaves, another person comes in and asks for the same TV and it turns out that the pawn shop owner made the mistake and gave the wrong device to the main hero. When the hero comes back home and turns on the TV, a portal to another dimension is created and he is sucked in.

I think that the comic book might be in European style, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comic book series is *Timothee Titan* by Giorgio Cavazzano.

- [Volume 1](https://www.bedetheque.com/BD-Timothee-Titan-Tome-1-Rendez-vous-sur-Proctor-V-24156.html)
- [Volume 2](https://www.bedetheque.com/BD-Timothee-Titan-Tome-2-L-avaleur-d-etoiles-109566.html)

I've recently visited the library in my hometown and there it still was in the stack of comic books. It has been 3 years since I've asked the question, but maybe somebody will find this answer useful someday.